# Cannot Centre Text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to centre some text in the middle of the page but doesn't want to work. I have `text-align:center` on it which should be making it centred and also a `position:absolute` on it's parent (#select) to keep the background image fixed.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/29taB/

How should I be aligning the text centre?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/29taB/1/ ? by the way, CSS is total disaster..

Comment: What the hell are you trying to do here? It looks bad.

Comment: Yeh, I'm trying to revive something I was working on from years ago. I know it's messy.

Comment: show the code in the question

Comment: The text is centered in the #select div, except your left-padding. You should use margin instead. Change the background of your #select to get a better look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:absolute` will not take a `width` equal to its `parent`, so it's `width` is only equal to its content. you have to give `width : 100%` to `absolute div` for this problem, check this...http://jsfiddle.net/29taB/10/

Comment: Crap... I knew I was forgetting something. Thanks. I'll mark this as an answer as soon as it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

you can change your css #select as below

```
#select { position:absolute;width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give #select a width. In this case 100% and all is working as desired. As you gave the body the text-align, all text will be centered. Maybe you should move that to the #select to.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the padding-left and assign a 100% to the #select you will center all:

```
#select { position:absolute;width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove padding and apply width 100%:

```
#select { position:absolute;width: 100%;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/29taB/11/)